# Dynaimic JSON parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am having below JSON object which I need to parse and populate value only last children available for that object in that list.

```
        {
         "projectInfo": {
        "cabinetInfo": [
          {
            "nodeName": "EAST",
            "boxName": "EAST-Box",
            "children": [
              {
                "nodeName": "Street-3",
                "smsName": "smsname",
                "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
              },
              {
                "nodeName": "Street-2",
                "smsName": "smsname",
                "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
              },
              {
                "nodeName": "Street-1",
                "smsName": "smsname",
                "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "nodeName": "NORTH",
            "boxName": "NORTH-Box",
            "children": [
              {
                "nodeName": "ZONE1",
                "boxName": "ZONE1-Box",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "nodeName": "AREA",
                    "boxName": "AREA-Box",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "nodeName": "Street-3",
                        "smsName": "smsname",
                        "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                      },
                      {
                        "nodeName": "Street-2",
                        "smsName": "smsname",
                        "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                      },
                      {
                        "nodeName": "Street-1",
                        "smsName": "smsname",
                        "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "nodeName": "SOUTH",
            "boxName": "SOUTH-Box",
            "children": [
              {
                "nodeName": "ZONE1",
                "boxName": "ZONE1-Box",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "nodeName": "SOCIETY",
                    "boxName": "SOCIETY-Box",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "nodeName": "AREA",
                        "boxName": "AREA-Box",
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "nodeName": "Street-4",
                            "smsName": "smsname",
                            "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                          },
                          {
                            "nodeName": "Street-3",
                            "smsName": "smsname",
                            "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                          },
                          {
                            "nodeName": "Street-2",
                            "smsName": "smsname",
                            "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                          },
                          {
                            "nodeName": "Street-1",
                            "smsName": "smsname",
                            "boxserilaNumber": 4004342423
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
        }
        }
```

I wrote below piece of code, but it is printing 3 boxserilaNumber whereas it should print 9. I am new to javascript, so not able to figure it out where i have done wrong here, to not get the correct output. I think the problem lies in
renderCabinetInfoList method where i am making recursive calls to reach bottom of the list which is having children

```
function renderCabinetInfo(nodeTree)
{
    var cabinetLists = nodeTree.projectInfo.cabinetInfo;
    for(var j=0;j<cabinetLists.length;j++)
    {
        var cabinetList = cabinetLists[j].children;
        var cabinetInfoTags = renderCabinetInfoList(cabinetList);
        var cTable=document.getElementById('cabinetInfoTable');
        for(var i=0;i<cabinetInfoTags.length;i++)
        {
            console.log(cabinetInfoTags[i].boxserilaNumber);
        }
    }  
};
function renderCabinetInfoList(cabinetList)
{
    for(var i=0;i<cabinetList.length;i++)
    {
        var cabi = cabinetList[i];
        if(haveChildren(cabi)) {
            renderCabinetInfoList(cabi.children);
        }
        else
        {               
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return cabinetList=cabinetList;
}
function haveChildren(cabi)
{
    if (null != cabi.children && cabi.children.length>0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The example JSON is neither an array nor a valid JSON. It could be a copy-paste issue, please check and update your question. Also, it is not clear what output do you expect.

There is [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) method that could be useful to extract nested values.